# Return first and last element in sequences

Tags: ruby

I have an array that consists of concatenated sets of incremental (+1) sequences. Here's an example with three sequences:

```
sequences = [2,3,4,7,12,13,14,15]
```

I'm trying to get first and last element of each sequence and return an array with those values. From the array above, the result should look like this:

```
[[2,4][7,7][12,15]]
```

I've come up with this pretty naive solution that I thought would work, but it only returns the first sequence. Any idea why? And/or any suggestion of a better solution in whole?

```
new_array   = []
start_point = sequences[0]
end_point   = sequences[0]

sequences.map do |element|
  if element == end_point + 1
    end_point = element
  elsif element == end_point
    next
  else
    new_array << [start_point, end_point]
    startpoint   = element
    end_point = element
  end
end
return new_array
```

Comment: You deserve some bonus points for thinking in C but writing in Ruby! However, doing so in Ruby can often lead to horribly inefficient code. Instead, whenever possible, use the built-in functional-programming-esque methods like `map`, `inject`, `tap`, and `select`. All of those methods are implemented in C, so the interpreter has significantly less to do when performing your algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) to find consecutive numbers: (this is also an example in the docs)

```
sequences.chunk_while { |i, j| i + 1 == j }.to_a
#=> [[2, 3, 4], [7], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

And [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) along with [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at) to extract each sub-array's first and last element:

```
sequences.chunk_while { |i, j| i + 1 == j }.map { |a| a.values_at(0, -1) }
#=> [[2, 4], [7, 7], [12, 15]]
```

Or more verbose:

```
....map { |a| [a.first, a.last] }
```